# Cloak/Exclude folders in Source Settings in tfs 2013 build definition from Team Foundation Git repository

Tags: git, tfs, build, build-process

We are using TFS 2013 build with Git repository. For continuous integration builds I want to exlude/cloak specific **folders** in the Git repository. It is a simple task if the build definition is monitoring a named single branch (e.g. /refs/heads/develop branch). However, we are using Git Flow for branch management and our build definition is monitoring all/any branch(es) in the Git repository.

In short the question is, when a build definition is monitoring all branches under a Git repository, is there a way (wildcard options) to exclude a folder from the monitoring list? *I would like to exlude the 'BuildProcessTemplates' folder from the monitoring list that lives under the Git repository.*

The image below shows Source Settings section of the build definition where the build definition is monitoring all the branches under the Git repository.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Git works differently to TFVC, and when a build occurs it's not folders that get checked out, like they would be with TFVC. Instead, it's actually a commit that is retrieved (i.e. the commit a branch points to) and all of the folders and files that the commit represents.